# Pcpp preprocessor API how to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, c-preprocessor

I have a C header file and need to parse it to do some checking at build time. So I am currently trying to use [`pcpp`](https://pypi.org/project/pcpp/) for that. I did not find any examples on [github](https://github.com/ned14/pcpp/blob/master/README.rst) regarding how to use the API except [comments in source code](https://ned14.github.io/pcpp/). [The examples](https://github.com/ned14/pcpp/blob/master/pcpp/pcpp_cmd.py) reference does not seem to work anymore. I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import sys
import pcpp

def check_directive(directive):
    #do the checking
    #...

class Checker(pcpp.Preprocessor):
    def on_directive_handle(self, directive, toks, ifpassthru, precedingtoks):
        print("Checking directive...")
        check_directive(directive)
        super(pcpp.Preprocessor, on_directive_handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c_header_path = sys.argv[1]
    with open(c_header_path) as fd:
        c_header = fd.read()

    checker = Checker()
    checker.parsegen(c_header)
```

But not checking was done and no diagnostic output `Checking directive...` was produced.

Can someone provide a working example using the API? Or probably advice another python module for that kind of task?